# Paypal Standard Not Working After Upgrade

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, upgrade

I have Upgraded Magento from 1.4 To 1.7.0.2, Previously on site PayPal Standard was working fine. I have again entered the merchant email, Set Payment Action to "Sale", Set Enable SSL verification to "No".

But After Clicking Pay Now button on PayPal I am getting the following error:

> Return to merchant and try a different payment method. We are not able
>   to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please
>   return to the merchant's website and try using a different payment
>   method (if available).

I have enabled the debug mode to Yes. But log file also not created. I have checked the permission too.

Please Help!!

Comment: Do I need to change some Settings in Merchant Paypal Account ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was due to invalid Merchant Email Id.

Hope this will help someone else